# Angular filter pipe on nested array

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

We are trying to use an angular pipe to filter a list of sub items, (if no items then parent item is removed)
HTML :-

```
   <div class="row border-bottom item" *ngFor="let item of pageContent | filter: searchText; let i = index">
      <div class="col-6">{{item.name}}</div>
      <div class="col-6">
        <ul>
          <li *ngFor="let link of item.content">
            {{link.content}}
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
```

our pipe is like this :-

```
export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
transform(items: AllContent[], searchText: string): AllContent[] {

if (!items) return [];
if (!searchText) return items;


return items.filter(item => {
  item.content.filter(c => c.content.toLowerCase().includes(searchText.toLowerCase()))
})
```

we cannot get this filter to work and it literally not filtering the the child items out.

we have also tried

```
return items.foreach(item => {
item.content.filter(c => c.content.toLowerCase().includes(searchText.toLowerCase()))
})
```

is there somthing that we are missing?

Comment: What if you remove the {} brackets and change the second filter to every?

Comment: how are you making the `pipe` to be triggered in the first place? by an `input` listening for changes? The pipe itself is not gonna work if nothing is changing the list of items..., `pipes` are pure meaning they only react if there was actually a change

Comment: [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular6-filter-pipe?file=src%2Fapp%2Fsearch-pipe%2Ffilter.pipe.ts) is a stackblitz example of a filter pipe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a `return` statement in the filter method and you need to add `.length`:

```
return items.filter(item => {
  // add the return below and append .length at the end
  return item.content.filter(c => c.content.toLowerCase().includes(searchText.toLowerCase())).length
})
```

When it's a one-liner, you don't need the `return`, but when breaking it to multiple lines using the `{...}`, then you need to return the items. Same with `array.map()`.

What @Adam Jenkins mentions in the comment is important to note. The condition in an `array.filter()` method needs to return either `true` or `false` (or a truthy or falsey value). The nested `.filter()` (on the inside) however returns an array, which is always truthy. This means the outside `.filter()` method, and therefore the pipe, will always return all of the items. To get around this you could add `.length` at the end of the nested `filter()` method. This will return a number based on how many items are included in the array returned by the nested `.filter()`. If it has 1 or more items, the condition will be truthy and the pipe will return the pageItems that has content that includes the searched text. If the nested `filter()` returns 0 items in its array, the condition will be falsey, in which case the pipe will not return that pageItem.

Another solution could be to use the `.some()` method, which returns `true` or `false`. This array stops when it hits true, in which case it won't have to continue iterating over the rest of the items. This is better for performance.

If you want to filter both the pageItem and content of the pageItem then you could do the following (assuming the pipe resets the items when filtering. Not sure if it does.):

```
items = items.filter(item => {
    item.content = item.content.filter(c => c.content.includes(searchText))
    return item.content.length ? true : false
})
return items
```

Also, the way it's written it looks like an item has a property of `content` which has a property of `content` inside it. Not sure if this is what you intended, but this code is assuming that that is correct.

Comment: I would imagine you should also add .length to the end of this, otherwise it’ll always be truthy. Cheaper to use .some than a nested .filter

Comment: Mutation is such a really terrible idea

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies in how you're using the filter function. The filter function creates a new array with all elements that pass the test implemented by the provided function. However, in your current implementation, you're using filter on the parent item, but not returning the result of this operation.

Here's the corrected version of your custom pipe:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
@Pipe({
    name: 'filter'
})
export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(items: AllContent[], searchText: string): AllContent[] {
        if (!items) return [];
        if (!searchText) return items;
        return items.filter(item => {
            item.content = item.content.filter(c => c.content.toLowerCase().includes(searchText.toLowerCase()));
            return item.content.length > 0; // Filter out parent items with no matching sub-items
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for this, id actally been down this route, and it works when searching,  however,  when clearing the items back out from the search,  it doesnt re-populate the array unfortunatly

Answer (score 0):

try to use map, map will filter the array and will return new array of items

```
export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(items: AllContent[], searchText: string): AllContent[] {
    if (!items) return [];
    if (!searchText) return items;

    return items
      .map(item => { // Use map to transform each item
        return {
          ...item,
          content: item.content.filter(c => c.content.toLowerCase().includes(searchText.toLowerCase()))
        };
      })
      .filter(item => item.content.length > 0); // Use filter to remove items with no content
  }
}
```